# Read message from a certain client in Lidgren

Tags: c#, networking, lidgren

I'm setting up a game with Lidgren, and I was wondering if there was a way to read a message from a certain client instead of just from the server as a whole, such as-

```
//Why doesn't this exist?
NetIncomingMessage message = server.Connections[0].ReadMessage();
```

This way I would be able to split up reading data from each client into it's own thread and have a separate thread for sending data to each client.  Currently there is only one loop in my server, which reads packets and I fear is favoring one client more than others, as some movements made by players take a while to be received by other players.  I believe reading messages separately from each client would solve this issue.  With simple TcpClients, you can read from each client's stream instead of the server as a whole, and I like this functionality but also rely on the simplicity of sending packets through Lidgren and was wondering if there was a similar functionality with Lidgren.

Answer (score 0):

You can read messages on one thread, then stuff them into a concurrent safe collection in the, for example, connection.Tag message. Each individual thread would then dequeue messages for that connection.
However; it sounds like a really bad solution to a problem that I assume is a bug in the existing code... there's no reason reading messages on a single thread would favor any client over another; messages are enqueued and dequeued in the exact order they arrive.
Doing one thread per client will create a whole bunch of synchronization issues you must solve when acting on the content of your received messages; I would advice against it unless you have a very compelling reason.